# VBA Subscript out of range on selection

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 values in *sheet1* which I want to migrate to *sheet2*. As of now my my *CommandButton* works fine till the point I create a *newsheet*. But as soon as I select my *newsheet* it gives me a *subscript out of Range error*. On commenting my last code of line the program runs fine.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim CustomerName As String, CustomerProblem As Integer, newSheet As Worksheet, newName As String


Do
    newName = Application.InputBox("What do you want to name the new sheet?", Type:=2)
    If newName = "False" Then Exit Sub: Rem cancel pressed

    Set newSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1))

    On Error Resume Next
        newSheet.Name = newName
        newName = Error
    On Error GoTo 0

    If newName <> vbNullString Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        newSheet.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        MsgBox newName
    End If
Loop Until newName = vbNullString

Worksheets("sheet1").Select
CustomerName = Range("C4")
CustomerProblem = Range("C5")
```

**This line gives me the error.**

```
Worksheets("newName").Select
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything within quotes will be considered as a string and not a variable. Change

```
Worksheets("newName").Select
```

to

```
Worksheets(newName).Select
```

Also there is hardly any need to use `.Select/.Activate`. You may want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

**Followup from comments**

Is this what you are trying?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim CustomerName As String
    Dim CustomerProblem As Integer
    Dim newSheet As Worksheet
    Dim newName As Variant

    Do
        newName = InputBox("What do you want to name the new sheet?", _
                           "Please enter a sheet name")
        If newName = False Or Len(Trim(newName)) = 0 Then Exit Sub

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        On Error Resume Next
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(newName).Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        Set newSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1))

        newSheet.Name = newName

        newSheet.Activate
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: In that case, Check what is the value of `newName`? It cannot be blank or cannot contain unwanted spaces. It has to contain the exact name as that of the worksheet.

Comment: if you take a look at the code above. I am getting the name of the worksheet as an input from the user.  newSheet.Name = newName

Comment: Do you want to add a new sheet with the name that the user provides?